# why does uploading .sql file into psql is not working for me

Tags: postgresql, psql

how do i upload my .sql file into psql terminal

```
\i FILE 'C:\\Users\insjm\Downloads\person.sql'
```

> FILE: No such file or directory

I get error like this

Comment: Remove `FILE` - `\i` is enough.

Comment: Why is only one of the backslashes doubled?